# How to call a rosservice within a python code?

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to write a code in python where I want to be able to run a node or a launch file, and do a rosservice call with an argument.
I am trying to find some examples , please kindly guide me if you know of any good examples to start with or if you know how to do it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245883/how-to-call-a-rosservice-within-a-python-code?/) by [Abdullah](https://answers.ros.org/users/27483/abdullah/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-10-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One of the many [ROS Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) describes the process for writing a [service client in python](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28python%29).

If you're having trouble following that, please ask a new question, provide a code sample and do your best to describe what isn't working.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2